# UIWebView application using proxy server

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, proxy

I'm trying to make a UIWebView application, just like any other (with refresh, go forward, back, google search, etc). It is going to be very simple. One thing I want to do however, is make the data loaded into the UIWebView loaded through a proxy server (like hideMyAss) - so websites like at schools or workplaces become unblocked.

I have been looking for a proxy which enables me to input the website address at the end of a proxy's URL, but I have not found one.

E.g. Hidemyass.com?url=google.com

Does Apple have any documentation as to how I could achieve this. I have no idea where to start looking as I don't know the exact name of what if be looking for. Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class that will handle all web protocols such as HTTP, HTTPS, SSL etc. This is a abstract class that provides the basic structure for performing protocol-specific loading of URL data. [Guide on NSURLProtocol](http://nshipster.com/nsurlprotocol)

Once your created your custom url protocol handler, register it in your appDelegate so your protocol will have priority over any of the built-in protocols.

```
 [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyURLProtocol class]];
```

In terms of proxy, create your own server and implement a ready made solution that will do all your tunneling of client data to outside world. [Tinyproxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/) is a example of a free software that can do your proxy requirements, research others or even create your own solution if you got the time.